# How to add suffix to only 1 option in angularjs select based on data variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a select like this in angularjs,

```
<select id="contact">
     <option value="HOME">Home - {{data.Home}}</option>
     <option value="WORK">Work - {{data.Work}}</option>
     <option value="GYM">Gym - {{data.Gym}}</option>
</select>
```

How can I add text "Preferred" to end of option based on variable `data.Preferred`

`data.Preferred` value is same as option's values.

Comment: So, the option stored in data.Preferred should have Preferred add to its text in the option? Is that correct?

Comment: @pedromarce yes that's truth

Comment: I think it would be better to add that in the controller, rather than the view, would that be possible? Could you show your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would make more sense, if possible to decorate it in the controller, but something like this should work:

```
<select id="contact">
  <option value="HOME">Home - {{data.Preferred === 'HOME' ? 'Preferred' : ''}}</option>
  <option value="WORK">Work - {{data.Preferred === 'WORK' ? 'Preferred' : ''}}</option>
  <option value="GYM">Gym - {{data.Preferred === 'GYM' ? 'Preferred' : ''}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it doesn't work until I add it like this - {{data.Preferred === 'HOME' ? 'Preferred' : '' }}, please add this to your answer, thank you